# How OR Xor And blocks of memory

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, xor

We have two bitmap such as bitmap1,bitmap2.both initialized with malloc(same parameters). Bitmap1 is assigned such as 0010 0110 and bitmap2 is assigned with 1000 0001. How we do OR operation between bitmaps to make 1010 0111. On the other hand, we want to set bits of bitmap1 that are 1 in corresponding entry in bit2.

We don't want to use some approaches such as:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) bitmap1[i] ||= bitmap2[i];
```

Because these approaches are slower than some functions (e.g. memset,memcpy).
Any guidance would be useful.
Programming language is C/C++

Comment: Please tag with the language you're using, rather than useless vague tags like "logical".

Comment: What makes you think that there are any significant performance issues with a straightforward approach using a for loop and bitwise operators ?

Comment: I want to use this program in a OS source code. So I need to use faster method.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the bitwise `or` and `xor` commands.

`or_result = bitmap1 | bitmap2`

`xor_result = bitmap1 ^ bitmap2`

If this will not work because of how you've defined your bitmap1 and bitmap2 (which is unclear, is it a `struct` or an `int` or a `char` or something less useful like an array or something strange like a class with an `operator[]` defined?  We need more information) then you'll probably have to change how you're storing your data.